# optim function: how to restrict number of decimal places?

Tags: r, optimization, decimal, digits, optim

I am using the optim function in R to analyze how people percieve distributions. My usual code looks like this:   `val.FR<-optim(par=0, fn=Frequency.Regression, method=c("Brent"), lower = 0, upper = 1)`

It seems like `optim` is increasing the parameter from 0 to 1 in very small steps. However I only need accuracy to the second digit after the decimal. Everything better than a 0.01 increase of the parameter is unnecessary. Can anyone tell me how to restrict the optimization process to two digits after the decimal?

I tried googling the problem and played around with reltol and abstol but with no success :/

Comment: try to add:      , control = list(maxit = 100, parscale = 0.01))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why is this a problem?  Are you running into long runtimes?